# Shouldn't I be notified if the community/moderators flag/delete a comment of mine?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, comments, comment-flags

I know comments are just a small feature and not mainstream in anyway. But shouldn't I be notified when my comment is flagged or deleted?

No notification on upvoting is OK and makes much sense, but notification on flagging/deleting is something different I guess.

In my work, I have a principle of not informing user of "everything" he makes RIGHT, but "everytime" inform them of making something WRONG.

Comment: Some of our higher reputation users have literally _thousands_ of (now) obsolete comments on Stack Overflow, which are pruned at the rate of several hundred a day. What you are suggesting would create an _enormous_ amount of noise for many people, and I don't see much benefit to it. Comments should be treated as temporary whiteboards, many of which will be ultimately erased if they don't help explain how an answer was derived. If you did something really _wrong_ in a comment, you would be contacted.

Comment: @TimPost but this doesn't actually seems to be the case (I have recently reposted a comment since I saw it wasn't there, assuming I hadn't actually posted it), it was subsequently re-deleted - I was not contacted in either. I would be much happier knowing *why* my comment was considered incorrect (so I don't do it again), even if it doesn't appear as a notification I should be able to find the deleted comment/reason **somewhere**.

Answer (score 14):

I think this would be a very bad idea in practice.

For anything but the most offensive comments, any value in educating the user regarding what the problem was with their flag would IMHO be vastly outweighed by the need for the community to deal with the inevitable flood of challenges that would be posted to meta.

The mods are capable of messaging users or using other measures like account suspension or deletion if they find something *really* objectionable.

Comment: The point is to tell the user that this comment is not appropriate.

Comment: Thanks - edited my answer to address your question more directly.

Comment: Not to mention, this would irritate a whole lot of people at the rate obsolete comments are now being pruned.

Comment: @Tim Post Well it irritates me if something that I spent some of my time on is deleted without me knowing or knowing why.

Answer (score 8):

Comments are "second-class citizens" on SO (as opposed to questions and answers) - and they aren't expected to be valuable or permanent. As such, IMNSHO it makes no sense to send out notifications on those.