# Should we get notified of deleted comments we've replied to?

Tags: discussion, comments, notifications

If I post a reply to a comment and that comment gets deleted, I'd often want to delete my comment as it often doesn't make sense or is redundant.

In the interest of removing more of these comments, is it worth being notified when a comment belonging to someone you replied to is deleted? Maybe just for manual @notifies, or maybe for automatic ones too (leaning towards only manual).

Comment: Maybe just a way to find them, rather then a notified.   What about cleening up past cases of this?

Comment: That would be good too, but I think you'd get a lot more people doing it themselves if they were notified rather than having to go to a list somewhere.

Comment: Or a notifcation that goes to the list when clicked showing the most recent at the top of the list

Comment: I like that suggestion.

Comment: A related request for automatic notifications on comment deletions is rather unpopular: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/105338/191131

Answer (score 2):

This... Really kinda sounds like busy-work at best, and possibly harmful at worst (if someone is engaged in a heated discussion and thinks better of it, probably best to just let sleeping dogs lie rather than effectively signally to the other party, "you've got him on the run!").

Note that you can always leave another comment notifying the other party in a conversation if you *want* to make sure stuff gets cleaned up.

The motivation here is good, this just strikes me as perhaps too much additional complexity for an edge-case.

Comment: It's not an edge case, too many times conversation looks incompetent and meaningless because some comment in the middle is deleted. I have a suggestion to prompt user to flag for moderator review http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/281649/when-someone-deletes-comment-suggest-to-flag-for-deletion-of-dependent-comments?noredirect=1#comment914931_281649