# Automatic deletion of 'reply' comments

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-replies, deleted-comments

Kind of related to this question:

[Should we get notified of deleted comments we've replied to?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/118137/should-we-get-notified-of-deleted-comments-weve-replied-to)

I just deleted some comments that were a reply to a comment that was deleted. Unfortunately, the original poster had replied to mine, so there's now half a thread of comments left behind. As far as I'm aware (correct me if I'm wrong), there's no way to inform the other user to clean up, without adding another comment that I'll have to clean up myself later.

How about adding the ability for a commenter to specify if they're replying to a comment, and if that comment is deleted for any reason, then the reply (and subsequent replies) are also deleted. It would surely save a fair amount of cleanup effort.

I know there's a lot of questions relating to replies on comments, but I couldn't see any of them suggesting an 'auto-delete replies' feature. The one I found above is similar, but only goes as far as to suggest notifying the user to clean it up themselves.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If there are only one or two comments just flag them as obsolete.

If there are more then flag the post itself using the "other" reason and ask the moderators to clean up.

Comment: Would it not make more sense of the 'Obsolete' flag informed the commenter, rather than bug the moderators? Or does it do that already?

Comment: @Flynn1179 - probably it would make sense for an "obsolete" flag to inform the commentator. Why not make that a separate feature request?