# Make auto-deleting of comments (flagged as no longer needed) easier, if they @-ed a user that *only* has deleted comments under that post

Tags: feature-request, comments, comment-flags

We already make auto-deleting comments easier if they contain certain phrases.

Can we do the same if the comment contains `@user`, and that user has already deleted their comments?

If I make a comment that gets the feedback I need, and the feedbacker responds I can delete my comment, but it leaves the response dangling. I'm thinking of this sort of thing:

[image: conversation between two users, Jake and BMO]

In the above conversation, if BMO deletes *all* their comments, they should be able to flag the one that has `@BMO` (or any other user that only has deleted comments) and it be more easily auto-deleted. Note, that only having deleted comments under a question is distinct from never having commented.

I don't know if a heuristic is need to prevent abuse, but it would reduce the effort on moderators, and let comment flaggers have more power to clean up after themselves when they create a comment thread that's no longer needed.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/135464/282094  https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/251637/282094 - fair to re-ask.