# Add "read receipts" to comments and answers

Tags: feature-request, comments, answers

Although not that much useful, I think it is better to add "read receipts" to answers and comments (to notify the answerers/commentors about whether their answer/comment was read by the OP).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> Although not that much useful

Indeed, I don't think this is a very useful feature. I don't see why you would actually want this. It will only cause users to complain "you read my comment, but didn't answer!". Responding to a comment is not required, and we shouldn't make any suggestions it is.

If you really want to know if a user most likely read the comment, you can see the time the user was last online. For me, that is a good indicator if the user has read the comment or not.

Comment: I agree;  If a feature isn't useful it should be removed and/or never developed, far too many actual useful features that could be added to this platform.  We don't need another way for people to harass other people.

Comment: @PaulWhite: There's [at least one suggestion that would allow this more easily and more smoothly](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/183753/obsolete-comment-flags-should-notify-the-original-commenter-in-advance-of-modera).

Answer (score 2):

I think it would increase animosity a tad by knowing that you were 'seen' but not 'heard' when answering a question. It should be safe to assume that the OP is probably standing by with bated breath looking for a solution.