# Will I be notified if one of my comments is flagged?

Tags: support, flags, notifications

I don't see any area in my profile that would indicate this, unless I'm just missing it

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, only moderators can see comment flags in the flag queue.

This does exist as an unpopular feature request [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/105338/shouldnt-i-be-notified-if-the-community-moderators-flag-delete-a-comment-of-min).

Comment: Cool, didn't want someone to bring the hammer down on me for flagging their rude stupidity

Comment: It may be that comment flags are anonymous even to moderators (spam flags are, for example) - I can't remember for sure though :)

Comment: Thanks man, I'm trying to accept your answer but it says I have to wait 5 minutes :\  standby...

Comment: @Rory Comment flags are not anonymous, for moderators.

Comment: @kiamlaluno thanks for clarifying - I did try to raise one to test but apparently if a ♦ raises a comment flag on their own site then it gets automatically dismissed as helpful.

Comment: @kiamlaluno In the queue, they are anonymous. We can figure out who flagged it, but that just takes a lot of guessing and work we probably don't care about. (We have to find the right person, and then find their flags)

Comment: @Zizouz212 Strange, I recall they were not anonymous, when I wrote that comment, but it could be I was wrong.

Comment: On the other hand, there is [a pretty popular feature request to notify the commentor if their comment gets flagged as "no longer needed"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/183753/997587), made with the motivation to aid the cleanup process of such comments.

Answer (score 5):

Generally speaking, the author of a post is never notified of any flag for that post; this means the author doesn't get a notification through the Super Drop-down Collider, or a bar notification, which is the type of notification used to report a new assigned badge.
The author is notified if somebody leaves a comment for that post; in the case the comment has been left from a moderator, the author is notified even after the post has been deleted.

10k users see the list of flags pending for any post, but:

- They don't get any notification in the Super Drop-down Collider
- They don't see flags for comments
- They don't see flags for their own content
- They don't see custom flags

Just to be sure I am using the right name, this is what I call *Super Drop-down Collider*.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Apparently the "official" name for that is [The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66838/134300).

Comment: @M.Babcock lol!  Does anyone get notifications in "The StackExchange™ MultiCollider SuperDropdown™" for new flags then?  I feel left out!

Comment: @Rory Nobody gets notifications about flags.

Comment: @kiamlaluno ohh sorry I misread your answer - didn't register that you were talking about MultiCollider notifications for comments!

Comment: @M.Babcock Now that I have that name in your comment, I hope to remember the correct name, or I will have to add a screenshot all the times. `:)`

Comment: @Rory When I read the word "notified," I always think of that type of notifications. In this case, there isn't a bar notification either.